# Batch file "unc path not supported" copying files

Tags: windows, batch

I'm trying to copy files from a network location to my local computer using below script, but it gives me an error message of

> unc path not supported

---

**The Script**

```
SET DESTINATION=c:\temp\new
SET DATE_FROM=02/13/2019
SET DATE_TO=02/13/2019

> nul forfiles /P \\sdpw9123app\work\ActiveMQ\logfile /S /D +%DATE_FROM% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE 2> nul forfiles /M  @file /D -%DATE_TO% && > con ( echo @path && copy /V @path %DESTINATION% )"

pause
```

I also tried using some Robocopy commands but I couldn't get it to work either but ideally I'd like to use the `forfiles` command to perform the copy operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue seems to be with using the [`forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) command and it not supporting UNC paths. You can use [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) to map the UNC path for you, then just use the rest of the path after the `\\servername\sharename` that maps which contains folders you need to run the commands against. End the script with the [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) command to disconnect any temporary mapped drives created with the `pushd` command.

### Script

```
SET DESTINATION=c:\temp\new
SET DATE_FROM=02/13/2019
SET DATE_TO=02/13/2019

PUSHD \\sdpw9123app\work
> nul forfiles /P \ActiveMQ\logfile /S /D +%DATE_FROM% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE 2> nul forfiles /M  @file /D -%DATE_TO% && > con ( echo @path && copy /V @path %DESTINATION% )"
POPD

pause
```

> **Clarification**
>
> - Instead of using `forfiles /P \\sdpw9123app\work\ActiveMQ\logfile`
>
>   - Use `PUSHD \\sdpw9123app\work` on the line before the `forfiles` command
>   - Run the `forfiles` command line as `forfiles /P \ActiveMQ\logfile`
>   - Use `POPD` on the line after the `forfiles` command

---

### Further Resources

- [`PUSHD`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)

  > **UNC Network paths**
  >
  > When a UNC path is specified, `PUSHD` will create a temporary drive map
  >   and will then use that new drive. The temporary drive letters are
  >   allocated in reverse alphabetical order, so if `Z:` is free it will be
  >   used first.
- [`POPD`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)

  > `POPD` will also remove any temporary drive maps created by `PUSHD`

Comment: It's working fine now after adding PUSHD to map drive. But how to paste files by source folder structure. If files copying from \ActiveMQ\logfile then how to get it like c:\temp\new\ActiveMQ\logfile, with folder structure. Please help

Comment: please help me to copy files with source folder structure.. I'm getting no clue

Answer (score -1):

In batch files you need to use `%` twice when referencing variables, ie 
 `%%DATE_TO%%`, whereas you only need to do it once on the command line. Try fixing that, and see if the above works when you paste it into cmd.